# How to point subdomain to an ip and retain domain name

Tags: .htaccess, dns, ip, subdomain, a-records

Given:

- a domain w/ **gofather**: `gloriousdomain.com`

  - w/ nameservers pointing to server w/ **hostcrocodile**
- a subdomain: `sub.gloriousdomain.com`
- a server w/ **digitalpond** and ip: `123.456.78.9`
- an `A-Record`in **hostcrocodile** pointing `sub.gloriousdomain.com` -> `123.456.789`

How do I make it so that when I enter `sub.gloriousdomain.com` in my browser it doesn't just reroute me and change my url to `123.456.78.9`

---

#### cases where it's worked before

- **wordpress** :

  - when you first set it up, it does the whole *route to ip* thing
  - then you finish the setup w/ it asking the subdomain and magically it's fixed
- **redmine**

  - routes to ip until you type in the subdomain

#### Interesting facts

- When I ping `123.456.78.9` it pings back `123.456.78.9`
- I thought `passenger` on top of `nginx` was doing some work helping the resoloution for `redmine` and that's why it worked, but to test it I stopped the service and pinged my redmine box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was my ISP.

I reset my router thinking perhaps it was caching the page, turns out it was the ISP, they were serving me a cached version.